# How to use options in Chart js v3 custom plugin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts

I'm following the instructions from the official [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) to create a custom plugin.

I'm using TypeScript and React.

Currently, I'm trying with a dummy plugin that logs to console a message. When I define the plugin directly in the chart (inline) it works correctly. But, when I try to include options of the plugin in the options it shows a Typescript Error.

The error reads as follows:

```
Type '{ pluginPlugin: {}; }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType<"line">>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pluginPlugin' does not exist in type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType<"line">>'
```

I think all my problem is with TypeScript, because If I simply ignore the ts error, I can see the plugin working correctly.

The code of the dummy plugin is as follows

```
const dummyPlugin = {
    id: 'pluginPlugin',
    afterDraw: function() {
        console.log("afterDraw");
    }
}
```

An excerpt of the code of the chart where I use the plugin inline is as follows:

```
const myChart = new Chart(node, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {datasets: [], labels: []},
                plugins: [dummyPlugin],
                options: {}
});
```

In this case, the plugin logs correctly.

However, when I try to include some options for the plugin, the error mentioned above shows.

```
const myChart = new Chart(node, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {datasets: [], labels: []},
                plugins: [dummyPlugin],
                options: {
                    plugins: {
                        pluginPlugin: {}
                    }
                }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An answer for this can be found in the [`New Charts`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#typescript-typings) section of the docs, you will need to extend the options chart.js provides.

To do this you will need to add a `index.d.ts` file to your project in which you can add the following:

```
import {ChartType, Plugin} from 'chart.js';

declare module 'chart.js' {
  interface PluginOptionsByType<TType extends ChartType> {
    pluginPlugin?: { // Key is the pluginId
      customOption1?: boolean;
    }; 
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Updated documentation with specific example on how to add types to a custom plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/plugins.html#typescript-typings